# Imap funciona apenas na CLI

Tags: php, ubuntu, imap

A extensão imap do PHP funciona apenas através da linha de comando.

Ao chamar o script de outro lugar o retorno é:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imap_open()
```

Ao rodar um script simples na cli a função roda corretamente.

O servidor é PHP 7.1.15 rodando em um ubuntu16.04.

No momento estou sem pistas da causa ou outras informações e sem rumo, pra falar a verdade. Se precisarem de informações eu publico, pois não tenho ideia do que mais pode ser relevante.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você deve editar o `php.ini` do apache, o `php.ini` do cli é diferente, crie um arquivo chamado `phpinfo.php` na rais do teu servidor http, e adicione isto:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Execute assim `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` veja a parte que diz "Loaded Configuration File", como no exemplo:

[image: exemplo de caminho do php.ini no php7.2 em sistemas ubuntu]

No teu PHP vai exibir o caminho correto, então sabendo a localização edite o `php.ini` e então remova o `;` da linha:

```
;extension=imap
```

Ficando assim:

```
extension=imap
```

> Até o php7.1 os extensions eram assim:
>
> ```
> ;extension=mysqli.so
> ```

**Então salve a edição** e reinicie o Apache (se não reiniciar não funciona), comando por terminal provavelmente é este (com `sudo`):

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, segui os passos mas o problema persistiu. Corrigi a versão do PHP na postagem, é 7.1. Esse server tem varias versões instaladas.
Esse server tem arquivos adicionas de ini em conf.d:
/conf.d/20-imap.ini
E dentro do arquivo tem:
extension=imap.so 

No retorno da função phpinfo() esse arquivo esta listado em Additional .ini files parsed.